How can I find the area of the given circle in the figure?
I have the following question:

What we have is a square ABCD with side length of 1. We draw a diagonal through the 2 points and we get 2 triangles (ABD and BDC). We take one of them and then draw its altitude(EF). From F,we draw a line to the B . We now have an scalene triangle GCB and we draw a circle tangent to all 3 sides in it. How do we find its area?

"We draw a diagonal through the 2 points and we get 2 triangles. We take one of them and then draw its altitude. From the point where the altitude meets the base,we draw a line to the corner of the square where the diagonal was drawn from"  I have ZERO idea what this is describing.  Which two points? which two triangles?  Here're my questions.  In the middle of  the bottom line of the square there is a point with two lines coming from it. Can I assume that point is the midpoint of the base of square? and can I assume where it connects to the diagonal is the midpoint of the diagonal?

One way is to find the three side lengths and the area of that scalene triangle $\triangle GBC$, in order to find the inradius.

What did you try yourself?

Im sorry for the confusion everybody... I will edit my picture with points labelled. Thanks

@fleablood let me know if it is clear or not now

@peterwhy I was unable to find the lenght of the sides. I know what BF is but not BG. If im able to know BG somehow...

@Aig I tried to label the different regions like a,b,c etc... and form equations hoping to get some solution but failed.

@peterwhy that was my previous account but have lost its login credentials so created a new one. I was unable to understand what it means and could not comment on it... If you could simplify it a little bit it would be helpful. I got it that time but when I refered to it again, I was unable to get it...

(1) This info should be in the post. Please see how to ask a good question. (2) What are E and F, how are they chosen? (3) Also, your question seems to be a duplicate.

@Aig E is the centre of the square. F is the middle on the base of the square

As you know $BF$, find $BG$ by $BG:FG = BC:FE = 2:1$.

@peterwhy thanks for that info. and how can we find GC?

Same idea, find $CE$, then $GC:GE = 2$.

Ohh thanks @peterwhy. I was looking for an easier method compared to my previous question and you provided it :) . Thank you
